How can I fix my code for ScrollController animateTo not working in flutter?
class _DetailState extends State<Detail> {
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  GlobalKey anchor1 = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
  }
  
  void _scrollToAnchor() {
    final RenderBox? anchorRenderBox =
        anchor1.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    if (anchorRenderBox != null) {
      final anchorPos = anchorRenderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero,
          ancestor: context.findRenderObject());
      scrollController.animateTo(anchorPos.dy,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int idx) {
            if (idx == 0) {
              Column(
                children:[
                  // article text
                  QuillScreen(
                    args: QuillScreenArgs(document: Document.fromJson(post.content)),
                    readonly: true,
                    isWeboEditor: false,
                  ),
                  // comment title text
                  Expanded(
                    key: anchor1,
                    child: const Text('comments: 151'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            } else {
              ...comments list for Column...
            }
          },
        ),
        
        // comment textinput with Send Button, when comment send success, call `_scrollToAnchor`
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _scrollToAnchor();
          }, 
          child: Text('Send'),
        ),
      ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I need to scroll to the comment title(Comment Text Widget) when user sends comment success.
I use GlobalKey as anchor set to the widget Expanded (or maybe Text('Comments: 151')), in _scrollToAnchor() function, I get anchor1 position, but scrollController could not scroll to anchor1, is there any error in my code?
When I scroll to the top, it works.
But when I scroll to the comments list, I send my comment, it doesn't work for me.
And I debug many times and failed, so need some help.
Thanks

you did not gave scrollController to Listview
